# QWebengine open createwindow if target _blank

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebview

I have a code that suppose to open/create new window if the link is target _blank but, it doesn't do as intended and gives no action in return.

Here is the code:

```
class MyPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPage, self).__init__(parent)
    def triggerAction(self, action, checked=False):
        if action == QWebEnginePage.OpenLinkInNewWindow:
            self.createWindow(QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserWindow)

        return super(MyPage, self).triggerAction(action, checked)


class MyWindow(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.myPage = MyPage(self)

        self.setPage(self.myPage)

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserWindow:
            self.webView = MyWindow()
            self.webView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)

            return self.webView

        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    main.load(QUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Would like to know why it's not working, if possible.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you directly test the link in any browser you will see that the action is to create a new tab, so `windowType` is for that case the type `QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserTab`, at that time we create the new window and show it as shown below:

```
class MyWindow(QWebEngineView):
    [...]
    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            self.webView = MyWindow()
            self.webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            self.webView.show()
            return self.webView
        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)
```

Comment: Is it possible to close the second window if the first was closed?